# Regex expression to replace a word between two differents words in a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I would like to use a regex to replace a word `ABC` between two words `MNO` and `XYZ` with `''`, but not the occurrences of the word `ABC` that aren't between `MNO` and `XYZ`.

For example, given the following string:

```
Lorem ABC ipsum ABC bla MNO bla ipsum ABC asfg 123 hello ABC dd ABC XYZ hello ABC
```

The expected result would be:

```
Lorem ABC ipsum ABC bla MNO bla ipsum asfg 123 hello dd XYZ hello ABC
```

So the only `ABC`'s replaced are the three between `MNO` and `XYZ`.

I tried some regex expressions within `preg_replace` in PHP, but I had no success.

For example, in this one I don't know how to not match all but `ABC`:

`/(?<=MNO)(.*)ABC(.*)(?=XYZ)/g`

[Here's a test link](https://regex101.com/r/bC8aZ4/16).

I would appreciate using regex and `preg_replace` in this case.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Is it a requirement to use `preg_replace` or can `preg_replace_callback` be used, too?

Comment: Wiktor, `preg_replace_callback` can be used to.

Comment: Can MNO and XYZ occur more than once?

Comment: Wiktor, added one example to the question it may throw light on it.

Comment: Rarst, in this case only once, but it's something I don't mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `preg_replace_callback`:

```
$s = preg_replace_callback('~(MNO)(.*?)(XYZ)~s', function($m) {
    return $m[1] . str_replace('ABC', 'XXX', $m[2]) . $m[3];
}, $s);
```

Or, with lookarounds, to make the code inside the anonymous function a bit leaner:

```
$s = preg_replace_callback('~(?<=MNO).*?(?=XYZ)~s', function($m) {
    return str_replace('ABC', 'XXX', $m[0]);
}, $s);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/CBKZl)

Here, `(MNO)(.*?)(XYZ)` matches and captures `MNO`, all between `MNO` and `XYZ`
 and then `XYZ` into  three groups and inside the anonymous function, all `ABC`s are replaced only in the second group. Note the `s` flag at the end of the regex is required to make `.` match line break chars, too.

In the second example, `(?<=MNO)` is a positive lookbehind that does not consume text, and requires `MNO` to be present immedately to the left of the current location and `(?=XYZ)` is a positive lookahead that requires `XYZ` to be present immedately to the right of the current location and does not consume the text either, thus, no need for groups here.

It is much harder with a `preg_replace`:

```
preg_replace('~(?:\G(?!\A)|MNO)(?:(?!MNO).)*?\KABC(?=(?:(?!MNO).)*?XYZ)~s', 'XXX', $s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WI3bP4/1).

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!\A)|MNO)` - end of the previous match or `MNO`
- `(?:(?!MNO).)*?` - any 1 char, 0 or more occurrences, as few as possoble, that does not start an `MNO` char sequence
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards the text in the match buffer
- `ABC` - an `ABC`
- `(?=(?:(?!MNO).)*?XYZ)` - immediately to the right, there must be 0+ chars, as few as possible, that do not start  an `MNO` char sequence followed with `XYZ`.

Comment: In this case, it works with more than one occurrence of MNO and XZY. Not necessary by now, but I'll keep in mind if necessary. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This will work if there is just one occurrence of `MNO` and `XYZ` in the sentence.

Try this regex:

```
ABC(?!.*MNO)(?=.*XYZ)
```

Replace each match with a blank string

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/e7ePfk/1)**

**Explanation:**

- `ABC` - matches `ABC`
- `(?!.*MNO)` - negative lookahead to make sure that the current match is not followed by the `MNO` somewhere later in the string
- `(?=.*XYZ)` - positive lookahead to make sure that the current match is followed by the `XYZ` somewhere later in the string

**Code([RESULT](https://rextester.com/SZOHV12305))**

```
$re = '/ABC(?!.*MNO)(?=.*XYZ)/m';
$str = 'Lorem `ABC` ipsum ABC bla MNO bla ipsum ABC asfg 123 hello ABC dd ABC XYZ hello ABC
';
$subst = '';
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
echo "The result of the substitution is ".$result;
```

Comment: Works perfect, it's just what I need.

Comment: megatxi I feel that the solution provided by @WiktorStribiżew is much better and should be accepted as the solution.